# How to insert an iframe on linkedIn via oEmbed?

Tags: linkedin-api, oembed

I am trying to embed an audio player in an iframe (for instance: http://radio.immo/share/player_mini/video=false&digest=true&auto=true&resp=false&mode=broadcast&id=97475) to listen to podcasts or live
broadcasts within linkedIn posts.
Basically, however, my questions would be the same for any player or web application to be embedded in an iframe.

I managed to use oEmbed, as explained in the following post:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/embedding-content-linkedin-posts-using-oembed-david-max ,

I implemented it for test purpose on the following web page:

http://saooti.wikiradios.com/broadcast/42660-Emission-avec-Antoine

I added in this page a link:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/json+oembed" href="/attachments/HPUserContent/oembed.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsaooti.wikiradios.com%2Fbroadcast%2F42660-Emission-avec-Antoine&amp;format=json"/>
```

pointing to the json file:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "type": "rich",
  "provider_name": "Saooti",
  "provider_url": "https://saooti.wikiradios.com",
  "height": 41,
  "width": 319,
  "title": "Emission avec Antoine",
  "description": "Une &eacute;mission en direct pour Antoine... (Insertion, jeunesse, test)",
  "thumbnail_url": "https://saooti.wikiradios.com/attachments/images/broadcast/42660/image.png",
  "html": "<iframe id=\"iframe\" style=\"width:319px;height:281px;border:none;overflow:hidden;\" src=\"http://saooti.wikiradios.com/share/player_mini/video=false&digest=true&auto=true&resp=false&mode=broadcast&id=42660\"></iframe>",
  "author_name": "Saooti Admin",
  "author_url": "http://saooti.wikiradios.com/user/3-3-Saooti-Admin"
}
```

It doesn’t work:

when I share this web page, I get the matching photo, with a nice "play" button on it, but when I click the button, I am just forwarded to the page, when I was hoping to get an audio player in an iframe.
I guess it's because a validation from linkedIn is required…

My questions are:

- is it really a question of validation/authorization by linkedIn or did I make any mistake?
- If it is a question of validation/authorization:

  - which is the process to follow for retrieving this authorization?
  - Is this authorization granted by web domain ?

Thank you for your answers,

Comment: Did you manage to add the iframe in a LinkedIn article?